# What does FE stand for in "InvalidFEOpcode"?

Tags: opcode, clients, invalid-opcode

I've seen the name `InvalidFEOpcode` used in client implementations, e.g. in REVM:

https://github.com/bluealloy/revm/blob/8206193e65ad199a1dde1e79e38bf9ffe38118c9/crates/interpreter/src/instruction_result.rs#L27

What does "FE" stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FE stands for the `INVALID` opcode, which has the value `0xFE`.

From [evm.codes](https://www.evm.codes/#fe?fork=shanghai):

> Equivalent to any other opcode not present in this reference, but guaranteed to remain an invalid instruction. Equivalent to REVERT (since Byzantium fork) with 0,0 as stack parameters, except that all the gas given to the current context is consumed.

It is basically a catch-all opcode that is executed whenever an undefined bytecode is encountered during EVM execution. For instance, the opcode range [0xC0-0xCF](https://github.com/bluealloy/revm/blob/8206193e65ad199a1dde1e79e38bf9ffe38118c9/crates/interpreter/src/instructions/opcode.rs#L277-L292) is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

When an undefined or invalid opcode is encountered during EVM execution, the EVM essentially halts the execution and consumes all the remaining gas for the current transaction. This behavior is similar to the REVERT opcode with 0,0 as stack parameters, as you mentioned. A crypto marketing agency is a specialized marketing firm https://fracasdigital.com/crypto-marketing-agency that provides services tailored to the cryptocurrency and blockchain industry. With the rapid growth and adoption of cryptocurrencies and blockchain technology, there is a growing demand for marketing and promotional efforts to help crypto projects, exchanges, ICOs (Initial Coin Offerings), NFT (Non-Fungible Token) platforms, and other related businesses reach their target audiences and achieve their goals.

Comment: if this is ChatGPT, please delete the answer and explain in your own words